# How to add custom method to Python class?

Tags: python

I need to accept emails via SMTP, for this decided to use `SMTPD Lib` in Python. There is a class `SMTPChannel` - is it possible to add a method to this class? I rather need not extend it, but do something that my method would be there on load...

Comment: For a pretty extensive discussion of this and related topics (e.g. adding a method to an object instance), see this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically add members to anything at runtime, including methods. You just need to define the method as a function separately, and then augment the type with the method:

```
def someMethod (self):
    # do something with self

SMTPChannel.someMethod = someMethod
```

Afterwards, all objects of type `SMTPChannel` will have access to that method.

Note that doing this will not work with the name mangling Python does for members starting with two underscores. So you can’t really do anything, you can’t do with the `SMTPChannel` object from *“outside”*.